# Spring Boot - Starting 2 Tomcat services on different ports

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I need 2 seperate REST APIs in my project, binding and listening to different ports. If enabled, spring initializes a Tomcat with the port given in server.port parameter in application.properties file. I want to start an additional Tomcat service at a different port.

Ideally I would like to bind functions to calls with annotations just like I would with the original Tomcat service (e.g. `@RequestMapping @GetMapping` etc.)

Is there a way to achieve this without going through the hassle of manually initializing a new Service and binding functions to it?

Comment: Why do you want to bind these to two different ports?

Comment: As a project requrement. 2 client's 2 existing APIs use different ports and DTOs (with some same paths). We are expected to match existing interfaces.

Comment: And why don't you create two Spring Boot Applications?

Comment: The two interfaces mostly overlap and mainly do the same things. They simply have differences in data types and path names. It would make more sense to just have N different APIs simply translating these calls to a common set of functions.

Comment: you could build the application the right way with just one exposed port and put it behind an apache reverse proxy which listens on two ports (or just the other port, if running on the same host) and then redirects them to the common application ports. That way you don't mess up your application design and yet the client use cases work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to have two instances running on different ports and do the same job. Is it true?
If yes, you need `load balancer`.

If you are familiar with `eureka` and `zuul` you can achieve your goal by mixing them.

I list the general steps but you need to do a bit of research.

1- create your application.
2- start 2 instances of your application and register them to `eureka discovery service`
3- create a `zuul` gateway and distribute the coming requests among running instances.